# inject a variable into the pipe when providing in angular module or component

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

this is my custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageFile } from './files/language';

@Pipe({
  name: 'lang'
})
export class NgxTogetherLanguageTranslatorPipe implements PipeTransform {
  language: any;
  constructor() {
    this.language = LanguageFile.language;
  }
  transform(value: string, falg = "fa"): string {
    if (typeof (value) != typeof ('x1'))
      return value;
    let key = value ? value.toLowerCase() : value;
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('languageFlag'))
      falg = sessionStorage.getItem('languageFlag') || falg;
    if (window && falg == "fa")
      return this.language[key] ? (this.language[key].fa || value) : value;
    else
      return this.language[key] ? (this.language[key].en || value) : value;
  }

}
```

is it possible i override another file or variable on LanguageFile  when i'm providing it into a module?

i have created a library for this pipe and i want to use it in multiple project, my challenge is want to use different files
this is
the file content :

```
export class LanguageFile {

    public static language = {
      "cancel": { "fa": "لغو", "en": "Cancel" },
      "ok": { "fa": "تایید", "en": "OK" },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's possible, you can use [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#basic-examples) to achieve this.

Basically, you can create token

```
const LANGUAGE = new InjectionToken<string>('language');
```

and on parent level provide value you want to use in your pipe (parent - module or component with pipe inside)

If you know value you want to use in compilation time, you can use something like

```
{providers: [{provide: LANGUAGE, useValue: LanguageFile.language}]
```

And if you need to use some logic in runtime, you can use [useFactory](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#defining-providers) instead

Finally, just inject value in your pipe like

```
constructor(@Inject(LANGUAGE) private language: string) {}
```

Comment: i used this pipe in other library and finally i used all libraries in a project.now i'm providing this into app.module.ts(main project) the result is it will apply on all component of the project but its not apply on libraries, how i can change to use in libraries? @alex

Comment: It's hard to say without code example. but base on description, check if module with pipe is imported in your lib (same or module where you lib used), and if pipe itself works, but language that you provide to it is undefined, verify that you provide language on parent level